# Ressources pour les comptes rendus de lecture ?

Tags: ressources, littérature

J’ai commencé à lire des classiques français comme *Candide*, *Les Lettres persanes* etc. Comme ça m’est difficile et qu’il faut que je relise une page plusieurs fois pour en comprendre le sens, je me demande s’il existe un site web qui contiendrait les résumés détaillés des livres classiques ?

Connaissez-vous par exemple les sites que consultent les lycéens français pour s'aider avec leurs comptes rendus de lecture ? 
Avant de commencer à lire, je lis bien sûr le résumé sur Wikipédia, mais je voudrais quelque chose de plus ample.

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce que tu ne t'intéresses pas à des livres plus "d'actualité" dans un premier temps ? Le vocabulaire et la tournure des phrase a beaucoup changé au fil du temps, tu aurais plus de facilité à comprendre.

Comment: Typo : *Letrres* should be *"Lettres"*

Comment: Les grands classiques existent souvent dans des éditions annotées et commentées, développées exprès pour suivre les programmes scolaires, tu peux peut-être trouver des infos intéressantes dans ce type d'éditions! (mon lycée remonte à un peu trop loin, je laisse le soin aux gens un peu plus au courant de te proposer des sites :-) )

Comment: @stbr Si celui qui a posé la question doit faire ces lectures dans le cadre de son cursus scolaire ou universitaire (ce qui est probable puisqu'il doit rédiger des comptes rendus de lecture) il a des lectures **imposées**.

Comment: @Laure Il / elle ne dit pas avoir à écrire des comptes rendus, il / elle demande comment les étudiants Français font  (sous entendus que ce type de comptes rendus pourraient l'aider à comprendre). C'est pour ça que j'ai posé la question.

Comment: @stbr Même si je n'ai pas à écrire des comptes rendus, je suis obligée de lire ces livres...

Comment: @Kerkyra Heu, ce serait super, mais  ici où j'habite les bibliothèques ne contiennent pas ce genre de livres :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne connais pas d'équivalent français à [Sparknotes](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/). Je peux signaler le [Salon littéraire](http://salon-litteraire.linternaute.com/fr/resume-d-oeuvre/wall) (vraiment très léger) et [Le Petit Littéraire](https://www.lepetitlitteraire.fr/) plus substantiel mais sur abonnement même si certains documents restent en libre accès, dont certains sur [*Candide*](https://www.lepetitlitteraire.fr/analyses-litteraires/francois-voltaire/candide/analyse-du-livre) qui te donnera un résumé chapitre par chapitre. Pour [*Les Lettres Persannes*](https://www.lepetitlitteraire.fr/analyses-litteraires/montesquieu/lettres-persanes/analyse-du-livre).

Bien sûr Sparknotes aborde la littérature mondiale ([*Candide*](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/candide/) par exemple) et tu y trouveras beaucoup de choses sur la littérature française, mais en anglais.